# wavefront set of a distribution

Tags: distribution-theory

If $(x_0,\xi_0)\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is a given point in phase space, how do I construct a compactly supported distribution $u$ which has

WF$(u)=\{(x_0,t\xi_0) | t>0\}$ ?

Comment: How do you define wavefront?

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this question also. I am using the definition that $(x_0 , \xi_0)$ is NOT in $WF(u)$ if and only if there is a pseudodifferential operator $P$ of order 0, elliptic at $(x_0 , \xi_0)$, such that $Pu \in \mathcal S$ (Schwarz space).